# serving a WordPress website downloaded from Chrome?

Tags: web-server, website, google-chrome, static-content

I used Chrome to download a website (using "Menu -> More tools -> Save page as ...".); I want to ftp the html file (renamed to index.html) and the files folder into a static http server and have a working web page. Will this work? (Note, I'm helping a friend who owns the content in question.)

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if the website itself is only a static page (e.g. HTML + CSS + JS). If you match the correct inclusion directories and locations it should start working.

This will fail though if you want to copy a site that uses a backend (ex. PHP), because usually you cannot access backend code and/or database through your browser.

Comment: It's a WordPress web page with what may be a custom theme, but all the links and menu options on the page just take you to other websites.

Comment: @EarlZedd You might be able to duplicate that webpage by copying together all references to themes and sources, and the page itself, but seems a lot of work. Wordpress has a lot of backend PHP code and keeps all changes to webpages in a database.